# Get current route in Symfony 3.3 and Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to have the current route in Symfony 3 in a Twig view.

I already did some research, but I didn't find any solution. I try the following in my Twig view:

```
{{ app.request.uri }}
```

It returns something like: `http://localhost:8000/_fragment?_path=_format%3Dhtml%26_locale%3Dfr%26_controller%3DFOSUserBundle%253ASecurity%253Alogin`

```
{{ app.request.get('_route') }}
```

Always returns NULL.

```
{{ app.request.getpathinfo }}
```

Always have: `/_fragment`

What I need is very simple. For an URL like `localhost:8000/article/5`, I would like to retrieve `/article/5`.How to do this?

Answer (score 13):

The following code snippet will do the trick:

```
{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) }}
```

`app.request.attributes.get('_route')` - returns current route name.

`app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')` - returns current route params.

`path()` - generates route path by route name and params.

This approach will not work for forwarded requests. In case of forward request, there is a [workaround](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5804#issuecomment-17379777): you should pass "_route" and "_route_params" to a forwarded params list.

```
return $this->forward('Yourbundle:Controller:action', array(
    //... your parameters...,
    '_route' => $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route'),
    '_route_params' => $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route_params');
));
```

Also you can use `app.request` to access any [Request](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) object functions, such as getPathInfo(), which should return current route path.

```
{{ app.request.pathInfo }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I read several sources saying that `app.request.get('_route')` is only for debugging purposes and that it can be slow.

Is it the same thing as `app.request.attributes.get('_route')`?

Is this problematic still relevant today?

Comment: "app.request" refers to a Request object, which is designed to be used in any part of your application (within any environment) to access request related info instead of using PHP globals.

Comment: Updated my answer with a workaround for forwarded request issue.